# rgl.setMouseCallbacks: Callbacks Cannot Restore Default Behavior

Tags: r, rgl

Once a callback is set with rgl.setMouseCallbacks, rgl.setMouseCallbacks( 1, NULL, NULL, NULL ) will not restore the default behavior.  Is this a bug or a feature?  Should I file an issue if it is a bug?

I am looking for information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a callback to `NULL` means "no handler".  When the docs say `NULL` is "the default value", they are talking about the default value for this function, not the default mouse handler.

If you want to restore the default value, you would use `par3d(mouseMode = r3dDefaults()$mouseMode)`.

If you want to restore the previous value (which might not be the default), you would need to save it and then restore it.  For example,

```
# save old values
oldmode <- par3d("mouseMode")
oldhandlers <- rgl.getMouseCallbacks(button)

# set new values
rgl.setMouseCallbacks(button, begin=..., etc.)

.... use them for a while ....

# restore old values
do.call(rgl.setMouseCallbacks, c(list(button = button), oldhandlers))
par3d(mouseMode = oldmode)
```

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the docs.  Also, I was able to revert the callback to the default using `r3dDefaults$mouseMode`. Thank you.